# I have a string and a number. I need to find the first sub-string that contain the same characters with the length of the number

Tags: numbers, substring

For example:

number= 3
my_string= "gghhsstttevvv"

The output:

"ttt"

*if the number was 2, the output is: "gg"

Comment: number 3, output  'ttt'. What about 'vvv' ??

Answer (score 0):

The below script will give you the desired output :

```
number = input("Enter Number")
string = input("Enter String")

count = dict.fromkeys(string,0)
for i in string:
    count[i] += 1

#print(count)

occurences = count.values()
#print(occurences)

result = [k for k,v in count.items() if v == int(number)]
if not result:
    print("No matching substring of length " +number+ " found")
else:
    print(result) # To print all the characters with the given count
    print(result[0]) # To print the first character with the given count
    output_char = result[0]
    frequency = count[output_char]
    output_char = output_char*frequency
    print(output_char)
```

Output:

```
python3 string.py 
Enter Number5
Enter Stringgghhsstttevvv
No matching substring of length 5 found

python3 string.py 
Enter Number3
Enter Stringgghhsstttevvv
['t', 'v']
t
ttt
```

Comment: hello and thank you for your help. Unrortunately I can only use if and loops of while and for. Is there another way?

Comment: Hi @ChenBar I've used if and for loops in my solution, there could be multiple different ways, but the general approach/flow would be similar to the above code.